# Scala - Spark Dstream operation similar to Cbind in R

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dstream

1)  I am trying to use MLlib Random Forest . 
my final output should have 2 columns

```
id, predicted_value 
1,  0.5 
2,  0.4
```

my feature sets are training data and scoring --- train , score 
but when I train and score I drop the id field as it could not be used as feature as it is unique for each row and has no intelligence in predicting, now I get the score predicted

my scored output looks like

```
predicted_value 
0.5 
0.4
```

But I want to tie it back to id

I am having id field in separate DStream  and predicted_value in separate DStream. How to I bind it to each other, I don't have any column field to make a join.

now how do I tie it back . For example R has a function cbind which can bind 2 columns from different data frames

```
x<-data.frame(cbind(testIds,p$p1))
```

Is it possible or any alternatives?

2) I am using a MLlib randomforest model to predict using spark streaming. In the end, I want to combine the feature Dstream & prediction Dstream together for further downstream processing.
How can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DStream.transform` and predict:

```
 dstream.transform(rdd =>  {
   val predictions = model.predict(rdd)
   rdd.zip(predictions)
 })
```